# bootstrap modal appers statcallyon page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-modal

I am workig on bootstrap [super admin templet](https://wrapbootstrap.com/theme/superadmin-responsive-admin-frontend-WB02N9M12). I add bootstrap modal in my page. but it appears statically on page load. withought toggle it.

I already include bootstrap js file so it is no issue.

I tried to solve this issue and I get some solution. But it is not proper. 
I write this code on document ready :

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('#question-form').modal();
    $('#question-form').modal('hide');
});
```

So each time I have to call **modal();** then I have to **hide** it. I can use **hide** directly it is not working. 
before **$('#question-form').modal();**
[image]

after **$('#question-form').modal();**

[image]

I added some screens, Hope you find diffrences. Before initilize modal it is totally like static HTML. after calling **modal()** it works normally. but by this solution it pop up and hide on every page load. Please help ;)

Answer (score 0):

just give necessary classes to the modal dive like bellow

```
 <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
```

and it will work